# what is the number in the zypher-jira tool for the defect indicates? 2|0

Tags: manual-testing

I have a zypher -jira tool and when i assign the defect to a test case i see there comes a number like this - 2|0, so what does that 0 indicates? and when will it gets incremented?

[image]